# how to export Vietnamese text to PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, itext, southeast-asian-languages

I'm facing a problem when trying to export a Vietnamese document as PDF using iText. 
I put Vietnamese words in .xml file like this

```
<td fontfamily="Helvetica" fontstyle="0" fontsize="9" align="0" colspan="48" lineoccupied="1">T\u1ED5 ch\u1EE9c tham gia</td>
```

then having java to get the phrases from xml file and convert it into Unicode using this method:

```
    public String convertToUnicode(String s) {
        int i = 0, len = s.length();
        char c;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(len);
        try {
            while (i < len) {
                c = s.charAt(i++);
                if (c == '\\') {
                    if (i < len) {
                        c = s.charAt(i++);
                        if (c == 'u') {
                            if (Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) != -1
                                    && Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16) != -1
                                    && Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 2), 16) != -1
                                    && Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 3), 16) != -1) {
                                if (s.substring(i).length() >= 4) {
                                    c = (char) Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 4), 16);
                                    i += 4;
                                } else {
                                    sb.append('\\');
                                }
                            } else {
                                sb.append('\\');
                            }
                        } // add other cases here as desired...
                    }
                } // fall through: \ escapes itself, quotes any character but u
                sb.append(c);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Generate PDF :: " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
            return s;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

After that, export String to PDF - encoding UTF-8. 
But the program failed to display Vietnamese character '\u1ED5' and '\u1EE9'
The output becomes "T chc tham gia"
Could you please show me how to fix this issue?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 [XML Worker examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples) involving Asian languages on the official iText web site. They parse an XHTML file containing Chinese characters, but it should be easy to adapt them to Vietnamese examples.

You can find the HTML files were going to parse here:

- [hero.html](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples#720-hero.html)
- [hero2.html](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples#721-hero2.html)

Both files contain the following text:

> 長空 (Broken Sword), 秦王殘劍 (Flying Snow), 飛雪 (Moon), 如月 (the King), and 秦王 (Sky).

In the first case, a font is defined using CSS:

```
<span style="font-size:12.0pt; font-family:MS Mincho">長空</span>
```

In the second case, no specific font is defined:

```
<body><p>長空 (Broken Sword), 秦王殘劍 (Flying Snow), 飛雪 (Moon), 如月 (the King), and 秦王 (Sky).</p></body>
```

These files contain UTF-8 characters, so we're going to parse them like this:

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
            new FileInputStream(HTML), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

The first thing you need, is a font that supports Vietnamese characters. That's something iText can't help you with. In your HTML file, you've defined Helvetica, but that's a standard Type1 font that is never embedded when using iText and that doesn't know how to draw Vietnamese glyphs. That's never going to work.

The first example [D07_ParseHtmlAsian](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples#712-d07_parsehtmlasian.java) will automatically search for a font named `MS Mincho`. If it finds that font (for instance because you have `msmincho.ttc` in your Windows fonts directory), the font will show up in your PDF. See [hero.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/xmlworker/cmp_hero.pdf). If it doesn't find a font with that name, then the glyphs won't be visible, because you didn't provide any font program for those glyphs.

The second example [D07bis_ParseHtmlAsian](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples#713-d07bis_parsehtmlasian.java) offers a workaround in case you don't have `MS Mincho` anywhere. In that case, you have to use an `XMLWorkerFontProvider` and register a font that can be used instead of `MS Mincho`. For instance: we use a font stored in the file `cfmingeb.ttf` and assign the alias `MS Mincho`:

```
XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
fontProvider.register("resources/fonts/cfmingeb.ttf", "MS Mincho");
```

The resulting file [asian.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/xmlworker/cmp_asian.pdf) is slightly different from what we expect, but now we can at least see the Chinese glyphs.

In the third example, the HTML file doesn't tell us anything about the font that needs to be used. We'll define the font using CSS like this:

```
CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new ByteArrayInputStream("body {font-family:tsc fming s tt}".getBytes()));
cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);
```

Now, all the text in the body will use the font TSC FMing S TT (stored in the file `cfmingeb.ttf`). You can see the difference in the resulting PDF [asian2.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/xmlworker/cmp_asian2.pdf).

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for your answer. However, I used BaseFont to solve this issue **BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(pdfArialFont, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);** . In where, pdfArialFont is a ttf file I put in working directory.

Comment: This solution helps to display not only Vietnamese but also Burmese language and more. Thank you for developing this fantastic iText :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an encoding as UTF-8 for your HTML and use &#xUNUM; for hex or &#NUM; for regular code to embed your special characters.  Not sure where but somewhere in your program since it is not display shown, but your final HTML should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML LEVEL 1//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Your Page Title</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->

     <td fontfamily="Helvetica" fontstyle="0" fontsize="9" 
         align="0" colspan="48" 
        lineoccupied="1">T&#x1ED5; ch&#x1EE9;c tham gia</td>

  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

You can cut and paste the above into an HTML file and view the result.  More reading pleasure is here [Unicode and HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML)